# add a new column with matching values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe and I am trying to add a new column with event-time of a particular action.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/run_terminate.csv")

df["_source_responseElements_instancesSet_items_instanceId"].value_counts()

i-0e1a1af5e49146950    2
i-03222a9b4df03882c    2
i-00b0e46026d56c6b6    2
i-06e3be34cdbac3c36    2
i-096dbc191934d6698    2
i-08b7f1ffece17a188    2
i-004785d32e1392117    2
i-06421f5f460be8b3a    2
```

There is a column called "_source_eventName" that has 2 important values. **RunInstances** and **TerminateInstances**. I am trying to add a new column with the date-time when the instance was terminated. In SQL I would self join the table on instance_id column and return non-matching event_names.

Comment: hi, could you show  an example how your expected output should looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved the expected results.

```
df.join(
    df.groupby("_source_responseElements_instancesSet_items_instanceId")[
        "_source_responseElements_instancesSet_items_instanceId", "_source_eventTime"
    ].transform(max),
    lsuffix="_left",
    rsuffix="_right",
)
```

I am not sure if it is the pythonic way!